# Bash Scripting: escaping star character

Tags: bash, shell, unix, console, sh

I have some code (Bash Script .sh) that generates me different combinations of characters.

When the variable "chars" contains the star with "\" (*), then generates a string with slash and star. But when I delete a slash in front of the star, then throws me a string of file names.

Does anyone have any idea how I can generate the correct string with a star?

```
min_length="1"
max_length="2"
chars="\` ~ ! @ # $ % ^ & \* ( ) - _ = + [ { ] } \ | ; : ' \" , < . > / ?"

generateCombinationsOfString() {

    for c in $chars; do

        nc=$[$nc+1]
        ch[$nc]=$c
    done

    for x in `seq 1 $[$max_length+1]`; do

        if [ $min_length -ge $x ]; then
            ci[$x]=1
        else
            ci[$x]=0
        fi
    done

    for clen in `seq $min_length $max_length`; do

            while [ ${ci[$[$clen+1]]} -ne 1 ]; do
                    wrd=""

                    for x in `seq $clen -1 1`; do
                        wrd=$wrd${ch[${ci[$x]}]}
                    done

                    echo "${wrd}"

                    ci[1]=$[${ci[1]}+1]

                    for x in `seq 1 $clen`; do

                            if [ ${ci[$x]} -gt $nc ]; then
                                ci[$x]=1
                                ci[$[$x+1]]=$[${ci[$[$x+1]]}+1]
                            fi
                    done
            done
    done
}

generateCombinationsOfString
```

Comment: What would be for you a "correct string" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in the following loop

```
for c in $chars ; do
```

cf.

```
chars='1 2 * 3'
for c in $chars ; do
    echo "$c"
done
```

Pathname expansion happens after variable expansion.

To prevent it, use an array:

```
#! /bin/bash
chars=(1 2 \* 3)
for c in "${chars[@]}" ; do
    echo "$c"
done
```